# Forward output_format to included templates

Tags: freemarker

I ran into a little problem with freemarker templates - or more likely with my setup.

Basically, I have two sets of templates:

1. Common templates, that centralize some textblocks that I would very much like to maintain centralized in one single file each.
2. Output formats, that produce either `HTML`, `XML`, Plaintext, etc. and that may include some of the common textblocks.

So far, I do not use the `ftlx`/`ftlh` auto escaping mode - every template is a "normal" `ftl` file. Since my output formats might be `XML`s, etc. I set `output_format="XML"`, etc. in the `ftl` directive of my output format templates that are meant to produce `XML`.

Unfortunately, `output_format` is only valid for the current template and not for the included templates, which leads to unescaped special chars (usual suspects like `<`, `&`, etc.) in my rendered `XML`. On the other hand, this behaviour makes perfect sense, since included templates might declare their own `output_format`.

Is there any way to escape the included template or override the `output_format` for included templates? Or will I have to duplicate all the textblock-templates for any targeted escaping mode (`XML`, `HTML`, Plaintext, etc.)?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output format of a certain section in a template is decided and becomes fixed when the template is parsed (not later, when it's executed), so it can't be assigned dynamically. It doesn't mater if the template is `#include`-d or it's the main template. So, if you have interpolations in the included "textblock templates", then you got a problem there for sure. If there're no interpolations there, then it doesn't mater, as the static text is never escaped anyway.

Let's say you have interpolations in those "textblock templates". One (admittedly awkward) workaround could be using the "undefined" output format for those templates, and then use legacy `#escape` like `#escape x as esc(x)` in them, where `esc` is the escaping function to use, which you assign dynamically. (Functions/methods are first class values in FTL, so you can assign them to variables. So you can issue `<#assign esc = someEscapingFunction>`, and then `#include` the template.) Certainly you will want to create some macros and functions to make doing this managable. Like you create a macro called `setDynamicOutputFormat` that somehow sets said `esc` variable based on its parameter output format, and then you start a typical template like this: `<#ftl outputFormat='HTML'><@setDynamicOutputFormat .outputFormat />`. Then when you `#include` something, `#escape x as esc(x)` will work properly in it.